# ADFS SAML response returns an invalid length base64 string

Tags: c#, base64, saml, adfs

I am seeing a very strange problem with ADFS2.0 operating as an IDP in a SAML authentication flow, essentially the SAML response that comes back from ADFS is an invalid length for a base64 encoded string. 
Even more confusing is that this doesn't happen every time, but seems to happen consistently for certain users Wednesday to Sunday, using the same systems and configuration without any apparent changes.

It appears that this is only for users that are authenticating within ADFS using NTLM. Users who are not on the domain and authenticating using challenge/handshake seem to work every time.

We're using the Kentor package for .net to generate the SAML request and have many customers using this successfully with ADFS as well as alternative SAML IDM 
systems such as Okta etc.

Help me stack overflow, you're my only hope

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow" While I sympathise with your situation, but you have the source code, you have access to the machines involved, you are accessing the web service. You know your users. We have nothing. How are we supposed to help?

Comment: Please consider giving us technical details about your problem. We cannot help you 'simply' with those infos. Problem might be everywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure what other information I can provide. I don't have access to the ADFS environment, it's a customers site, which is unique to them. I can provide the base64 string, but given that it's invalid I'm not sure what use that would be. I was hoping someone would have had a similar experience.

Comment: We need a [mcve].  I agree with @sefe, unless we guess blindly, I don't think this is answerable with the information provided, though I will admit my familiarity with ADFS is rather limited.